# How to remove line breaks AND save not empty lines in a list?

Tags: python, text, line-breaks

I have a text document (called hobbit).
I need to remove the line breaks from that document using the command rstrip().
I did this to remove the line breaks.

```
clear_lines = []

for line in hobbit:
    clear_lines = line.rstrip('\n')
```

(I'm not sure if this step is correct, is there a way to verify it? )

Now I need to save the non empty lines in a list.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In your loop you need to append your lines to the list. Assignment operation doesn't make sense there.

```
clear_lines.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

If you want to omit non empty lines then check against that condition before appending:

```
line = line.rstrip('\n')
if (len(line) != 0):
   ...
```

Also what is "empty line" in your program? Do you consider a line with only spaces as an empty one? If so then strip all "blank" characters before checking the length.

Comment: empty line in a sense of line break, so when someone has pressed enter and started a new paragraph

Comment: by the way if I use the command 
`clear_lines.append(line.rstrip('\n'))`
I get the error 
**'str' object has no attribute 'append'**

Comment: You wrote `clear_lines=[]` That creates an empty array. Array has `append()` method. If you are getting 'str' object doesn't have... then you have changed `clear_lines` to a string object. E.g. `o=[] o='abc'` sequence replaces array object with a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehensions for this

```
clear_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in hobbit]
```

To verify that this worked you can look over and check if any lines end with `'\n'`

```
any(line.endswith('\n')  for line in clear_lines)
```

should return `false`. If you want to you can [assert](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-assert_stmt) this.
Addition checks, such as to see if line is empty, can be added to the list comprehension above.

As an example:

```
hobbit = ['hello','world','there\n','\n']
clear_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in hobbit if len(line.rstrip('\n')) > 0]
```

clear_lines holds the values:

```
['hello', 'world', 'there']
```

In you case assuming the file is called `hobbit.txt` and saved in the same directory as your python file then:

```
with open('hobbit.txt','rb') as hobbit:
    clear_lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in hobbit if len(line.rstrip('\n')) > 0]
assert(not any(line.endswith('\n')  for line in clear_lines))
```

Again the assert is completely optional and mainly used for debugging purposes.